# VB.Net 'Sub Main' was not found

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application, entry-point

ok, I have an A level computing exam on Monday, and I have been working on the pre-release skeleton code.

This morning when I tried I got an error saying `'Sub Main' was not found`. There clearly is a `Sub Main()` in the code which I will paste in below.

I tried adding another `sub main()` before getting a second error saying `Sub Main() has multiple definitions`.

I really need to get this sorted, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for the Sub Main() by itself:

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim Choice As Char
    Dim Deck(52) As TCard
    Dim RecentScores(NoOfRecentScores) As TRecentScore
    Randomize()
    Do
        DisplayMenu()
        Choice = GetMenuChoice()
        Select Case Choice
            Case "1"
                LoadDeck(Deck)
                ShuffleDeck(Deck)
                PlayGame(Deck, RecentScores)
            Case "2"
                LoadDeck(Deck)
                PlayGame(Deck, RecentScores)
            Case "3"
                DisplayRecentScores(RecentScores)
            Case "4"
                ResetRecentScores(RecentScores)
        End Select
    Loop Until Choice = "q"
End Sub
```

And here is the full code if that helps:

```
 'Skeleton Program code for the AQA COMP1 Summer 2014 examination
 'this code should be used in conjunction with the Preliminary Material
 'written by the AQA COMP1 Programmer Team
 'developed in the Visual Studio 2008 (Console Mode) programming environment (VB.NET)
Module CardPredict
Const NoOfRecentScores As Integer = 3
Structure TCard
    Dim Suit As Integer
    Dim Rank As Integer
End Structure
Structure TRecentScore
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Score As Integer
End Structure
Sub Main()
    Dim Choice As Char
    Dim Deck(52) As TCard
    Dim RecentScores(NoOfRecentScores) As TRecentScore
    Randomize()
    Do
        DisplayMenu()
        Choice = GetMenuChoice()
        Select Case Choice
            Case "1"
                LoadDeck(Deck)
                ShuffleDeck(Deck)
                PlayGame(Deck, RecentScores)
            Case "2"
                LoadDeck(Deck)
                PlayGame(Deck, RecentScores)
            Case "3"
                DisplayRecentScores(RecentScores)
            Case "4"
                ResetRecentScores(RecentScores)
        End Select
    Loop Until Choice = "q"
End Sub
Sub Main()
    Console.Write("Boo")
End Sub
Function GetRank(ByVal RankNo As Integer) As String
    Dim Rank As String = ""
    Select Case RankNo
        Case 1 : Rank = "Ace"
        Case 2 : Rank = "Two"
        Case 3 : Rank = "Three"
        Case 4 : Rank = "Four"
        Case 5 : Rank = "Five"
        Case 6 : Rank = "Six"
        Case 7 : Rank = "Seven"
        Case 8 : Rank = "Eight"
        Case 9 : Rank = "Nine"
        Case 10 : Rank = "Ten"
        Case 11 : Rank = "Jack"
        Case 12 : Rank = "Queen"
        Case 13 : Rank = "King"
    End Select
    Return Rank
End Function
Function GetSuit(ByVal SuitNo As Integer) As String
    Dim Suit As String = ""
    Select Case SuitNo
        Case 1 : Suit = "Clubs"
        Case 2 : Suit = "Diamonds"
        Case 3 : Suit = "Hearts"
        Case 4 : Suit = "Spades"
    End Select
    Return Suit
End Function
Sub DisplayMenu()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("MAIN MENU")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("1.  Play game (with shuffle)")
    Console.WriteLine("2.  Play game (without shuffle)")
    Console.WriteLine("3.  Display recent scores")
    Console.WriteLine("4.  Reset recent scores")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.Write("Select an option from the menu (or enter q to quit): ")
End Sub
Function GetMenuChoice() As Char
    Dim Choice As Char
    Choice = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine()
    Return Choice
End Function
Sub LoadDeck(ByRef Deck() As TCard)
    Dim Count As Integer
    FileOpen(1, "deck.txt", OpenMode.Input)
    Count = 1
    While Not EOF(1)
        Deck(Count).Suit = CInt(LineInput(1))
        Deck(Count).Rank = CInt(LineInput(1))
        Count = Count + 1
    End While
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
Sub ShuffleDeck(ByRef Deck() As TCard)
    Dim NoOfSwaps As Integer
    Dim Position1 As Integer
    Dim Position2 As Integer
    Dim SwapSpace As TCard
    Dim NoOfSwapsMadeSoFar As Integer
    NoOfSwaps = 1000
    For NoOfSwapsMadeSoFar = 1 To NoOfSwaps
        Position1 = Int(Rnd() * 52) + 1
        Position2 = Int(Rnd() * 52) + 1
        SwapSpace = Deck(Position1)
        Deck(Position1) = Deck(Position2)
        Deck(Position2) = SwapSpace
    Next
End Sub
Sub DisplayCard(ByVal ThisCard As TCard)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Card is the " & GetRank(ThisCard.Rank) & " of " & GetSuit(ThisCard.Suit))
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
Sub GetCard(ByRef ThisCard As TCard, ByRef Deck() As TCard, ByVal NoOfCardsTurnedOver As Integer)
    Dim Count As Integer
    ThisCard = Deck(1)
    For Count = 1 To (51 - NoOfCardsTurnedOver)
        Deck(Count) = Deck(Count + 1)
    Next
    Deck(52 - NoOfCardsTurnedOver).Suit = 0
    Deck(52 - NoOfCardsTurnedOver).Rank = 0
End Sub
Function IsNextCardHigher(ByVal LastCard As TCard, ByVal NextCard As TCard) As Boolean
    Dim Higher As Boolean
    Higher = False
    If NextCard.Rank > LastCard.Rank Then
        Higher = True
    End If
    Return Higher
End Function
Function GetPlayerName() As String
    Dim PlayerName As String
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.Write("Please enter your name: ")
    PlayerName = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine()
    Return PlayerName
End Function
Function GetChoiceFromUser() As Char
    Dim Choice As Char
    Console.Write("Do you think the next card will be higher than the last card (enter y or n)? ")
    Choice = Console.ReadLine
    Return Choice
End Function
Sub DisplayEndOfGameMessage(ByVal Score As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("GAME OVER!")
    Console.WriteLine("Your score was " & Score)
    If Score = 51 Then
        Console.WriteLine("WOW!  You completed a perfect game.")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
Sub DisplayCorrectGuessMessage(ByVal Score As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Well done!  You guessed correctly.")
    Console.WriteLine("Your score is now " & Score & ".")
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
Sub ResetRecentScores(ByRef RecentScores() As TRecentScore)
    Dim Count As Integer
    For Count = 1 To NoOfRecentScores
        RecentScores(Count).Name = ""
        RecentScores(Count).Score = 0
    Next
End Sub
Sub DisplayRecentScores(ByVal RecentScores() As TRecentScore)
    Dim Count As Integer
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Recent scores:")
    Console.WriteLine()
    For Count = 1 To NoOfRecentScores
        Console.WriteLine(RecentScores(Count).Name & " got a score of " & RecentScores(Count).Score)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to return to the main menu")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Sub UpdateRecentScores(ByRef RecentScores() As TRecentScore, ByVal Score As Integer)
    Dim PlayerName As String
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim FoundSpace As Boolean
    PlayerName = GetPlayerName()
    FoundSpace = False
    Count = 1
    While Not FoundSpace And Count <= NoOfRecentScores
        If RecentScores(Count).Name = "" Then
            FoundSpace = True
        Else
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    End While
    If Not FoundSpace Then
        For Count = 1 To NoOfRecentScores - 1
            RecentScores(Count) = RecentScores(Count + 1)
        Next
        Count = NoOfRecentScores
    End If
    RecentScores(Count).Name = PlayerName
    RecentScores(Count).Score = Score
End Sub
Sub PlayGame(ByVal Deck() As TCard, ByRef RecentScores() As TRecentScore)
    Dim NoOfCardsTurnedOver As Integer
    Dim GameOver As Boolean
    Dim NextCard As TCard
    Dim LastCard As TCard
    Dim Higher As Boolean
    Dim Choice As Char
    GameOver = False
    GetCard(LastCard, Deck, 0)
    DisplayCard(LastCard)
    NoOfCardsTurnedOver = 1
    While NoOfCardsTurnedOver < 52 And Not GameOver
        GetCard(NextCard, Deck, NoOfCardsTurnedOver)
        Do
            Choice = GetChoiceFromUser()
        Loop Until Choice = "y" Or Choice = "n"
        DisplayCard(NextCard)
        NoOfCardsTurnedOver = NoOfCardsTurnedOver + 1
        Higher = IsNextCardHigher(LastCard, NextCard)
        If Higher And Choice = "y" Or Not Higher And Choice = "n" Then
            DisplayCorrectGuessMessage(NoOfCardsTurnedOver - 1)
            LastCard = NextCard
        Else
            GameOver = True
        End If
    End While
    If GameOver Then
        DisplayEndOfGameMessage(NoOfCardsTurnedOver - 2)
        UpdateRecentScores(RecentScores, NoOfCardsTurnedOver - 2)
    Else
        DisplayEndOfGameMessage(51)
        UpdateRecentScores(RecentScores, 51)
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

Thanks in advance,
 Ed

Comment: did you make card predict the entry point for the program? you can do this by double clicking the error and selecting that file as entry point

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to specify the startup object in order for `Sub Main` to be found. In your case this is the module `CardPredict`

Go to

`Project`>`[Your project] Properties`>`Application Tab`

Then set the `Startup Object` there.

I'm guessing that you renamed your `Module1` (the default) to `CardPredict` just before this error occurred?

in the future if you want to rename a class/module/method name, just right click on it and select rename. This will then rename all instances of this in your project to the new name.

Comment: ah, ok, now I get a new error when I run, the program opens but when I enter something in the menu, it crashes with this error -                   An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'c:\users\ed p\documents\School\Computing\Skeleton program 2014 pre release(cleanCopy)\Skeleton program 2014 pre release(cleanCopy)\bin\Debug\deck.txt'.

Comment: nice catch. btw, as a side note, you can also rename the module filename, and it will rename all occurrences of your main module/class/namespace contained in that file. at least for VB intellisense.

Comment: @EdPrince - sounds like the deck.txt file does not exist in the location specified!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I was working on a project and here is how I solved it:

`Project > ProjectName Properties > Application`

Change `startup Object` to `Form 1`, or the name of the startup form.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a main in your solution:

`Right click your project > Properties > Application tab > Application Type`

should be Class Library (maybe other); Startup object should be (None).

Answer (score 0):

In my case `Application.xaml` and `Application.xaml.vb` were missing from the project.

As they were not included, the Build tool doesn't generate the `Sub Main` method, which was set in the project Properties tab.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error when building my application; it stated that `Sub Main` was missing for my DLL.

For some reason the Application Type for this DLL had been set to Windows Forms Application. Changing it back to Class Library solved the problem.

`Project > Project's DLL Properties > Application`

Answer (score 0):

Not only
Project > ProjectName Properties > Application

Change startup Object to Form 1, or the name of the startup form.
work.
Also change the Target frame work to .NET 5 from .net3 or .net 3.1 in Visual Studio 2019.
It worked for me.